A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found TELEBOT
raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found
"


Here is my error in the code, it happens when I click Like, after that the code should remember this profile in the database as liked and send a message to the owner of this profile
I can't figure out why it's happening, here's my code:
    if user:
        name, age, gender, photo_id = user
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(" Like", callback_data=f"like_{random_user_id}"))

def handle_like_callback(call):
    user_id = call.from_user.id
    liked_user_id = int(call.data.split('_')[1])

    with conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO likes (liker_id, liked_id) VALUES (?, ?)", (user_id, liked_user_id))

    cursor.execute("SELECT telegram_id FROM users WHERE telegram_id = ?", (liked_user_id,))
    liked_user = cursor.fetchone()

    if liked_user:
        liked_user_telegram_id = liked_user[0]
        cursor.execute("SELECT name, age, gender, photo_id FROM users WHERE telegram_id = ?", (user_id,))
        user = cursor.fetchone()

        if user:
            name, age, gender, photo_id = user
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Reply", url=f"tg://user?id={user_id}"))

            if liked_user_telegram_id:
                bot.send_photo(liked_user_telegram_id, photo_id, caption=f"Name: {name}\nAge: {age}\nGender: {gender}",
                               reply_markup=markup)
            else:
bot.send_message(....)


I'm tryed edit
if liked_user_telegram_id:
            bot.send_photo(liked_user_telegram_id, photo_id, caption=f"Name: {name}\nAge: {age}\nGender: {gender}", reply_markup=markup)

Explanation:
handle_like_callback(call): This function is triggered when a user likes another user's profile (callback query). It retrieves the user_id (liker) and liked_user_id (the user whose profile is liked) from the callback data.
Insert into 'likes' table: Inserts a record into the 'likes' table in the database indicating that user_id liked liked_user_id.
Retrieve liked user's Telegram ID: Queries the 'users' table to fetch the telegram_id of the user who was liked (liked_user_id).
Check if liked_user exists: If a valid liked_user is found (i.e., their telegram_id exists in the database), it retrieves the data (name, age, gender, photo_id) of the user who performed the like (user_id).
Prepare and send message: Constructs an inline keyboard markup with a "Reply" button linking to the profile of the user who performed the like. Then, it sends a photo message to the liked_user_telegram_id containing the profile information of the user who liked, including their name, age, and gender.
Handle invalid liked_user_telegram_id: If liked_user_telegram_id is not valid or empty, it sends a message back to user_id indicating that the message couldn't be sent because the user was not found.

The solution turned out to be much easier, during development I used a temporary ID for testing, and I got this error because I couldn’t figure out who exactly to send the message to since -280, for example, a non-existent ID in the telegram
